# Values of sub-entities being converted to strings when they should be ints. Unable to add filters and query

Tags: python, filter, nosql, google-cloud-datastore, datastore

So say I create an entity with

```
def create_entity_from_key(kind: str, value) -> datastore.Entity:
        return datastore.Entity(key=datastore_client.key(kind, value))

def create_driver_entity(entity: datastore.Entity, name: str, 
        stat_totals: dict, team: str) -> datastore.Entity:
        entity.update({
            'name': name,
            'stat_totals': stat_totals,
            'team': team 
        })
        return entity

def create_driver_stats(age:int, pole_positions: int, race_wins: int, points_scored: int, world_titles: int, fastest_laps: int) -> dict:
        driver_stats = {
            'age': int(age),
            'pole_positions': int(pole_positions),
            'race_wins': int(race_wins),
            'points_scored': int(points_scored),
            'world_titles': int(world_titles),
            'fastest_laps': int(fastest_laps)
        }
        return driver_stats

#get the values
        name = request.form['name-tf']
        age = request.form['age-tf']
        #get rest of the values in the same way

#create the entity
        entity = create_entity_from_key('driver', name)
        #create the stats
        stats = create_driver_stats(age, plpos, rcwin, ptscr, wdttl, fstlp)
        #create the entity
        create_driver_entity(entity, name, stats, rctem)

        #put the entity into datastore
        datastore_client.put(entity)
```

When I try to fetch entities with filters, I get the wrong entities. ie the below code doesn't work as expected

```
attr = request.form['attr']
    value = request.form['value']
    #check if value is digit if it is, convert
    if value.isdigit():
        value = int(value) 
    query = datastore_client.query(kind=kind_type)
    #attr would be 'stat_totals.age' for example. I have confirmed that the correct string is being used 
    query.add_filter(attr, ">=", str(value))
    result = query.fetch()
    return result
```

When I checked the datastore, this is what I found

```
{
  "properties": {
    "race_wins": {
      "integerValue": "9"
    },
    "pole_positions": {
      "integerValue": "9"
    },
    "points_scored": {
      "integerValue": "9"
    },
    "world_titles": {
      "integerValue": "9"
    },
    "age": {
      "integerValue": "9"
    },
    "fastest_laps": {
      "integerValue": "9"
    }
  }
}
```

I'm not quite sure what's going wrong. I thought it was because of the quotes around the numbers. So I tried removing them, but once I saved the entity, the quotes came back.
I just need to be able to add filters to the numeric values and get the expected results.

I've tried typecasting to both str and int.

If I use the line `query.add_filter(stat_totals.age, ">=", 9)` I expect to only get entities with age > 9. Instead I get a lot more, I assume this is because the filter is comparing strings.

Comment: Instead of recasting the values passed in the `create_driver_stats` function have you tried directly assigning them ? because by looking at the output it seems that `integerValue` should be produced by the casting. Let me know if it worked ?

Comment: Directly assigning as in?

Comment: Yes just like `driver_stats = {
            'age': age,
            'pole_positions': pole_positions,
            'race_wins': race_wins,
            'points_scored': points_scored,
            'world_titles': world_titles,
            'fastest_laps': fastest_laps
        }`

Comment: Hi does that solved your issue ?

Comment: Nope, that's what I tried at the start

Comment: Then you can update the `create_driver_entity()` function to convert the integer values to int64 when they are added to the entity, as follows: `'stat_totals': {
                'age': int(stat_totals['age']),
                'pole_positions': int(stat_totals['pole_positions']),
                'race_wins': int(stat_totals['race_wins']),
                'points_scored': int(stat_totals['points_scored']),
                'world_titles': int(stat_totals['world_titles']),
                'fastest_laps': int(stat_totals['fastest_laps'])
            }`

Comment: I don't follow? how is that different from what was done previously